# Search multiple columns and return header

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have 3 columns of data - each one with no duplicates.  What I am trying to do is search of a specific cell data in one worksheet in 3 columns of another worksheet and return the header of the cell the information found in.  I first tried using "If" with Index/Match, then Vlookup, then Search...  I thought this was going to be a fairly straight forward formula, but I am stumped.  I must be missing something obvious... Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Say you are searching for `D1` in `A:C`. If you want **ONE** formula, you can use this:

```
=IFERROR(IF(MATCH(D1, A:A, 0), $A$1),
 IFERROR(IF(MATCH(D1, B:B, 0), $B$1),
 IFERROR(IF(MATCH(D1, C:C, 0), $C$1), "not found")))
```

I know this is not scalable. Many other solutions are possible. For example, set `E1` to

```
=IFERROR(IF(MATCH(D1, A:A, 0), A1), "")
```

and copy it to `F1` and `G1`. Now you can get the header like this:

```
=CONCATENATE(E1,F1,G1)
```

Comment: I see where you are going with this and modified it a little.  The issue it is not working when searching the other columns.  See here - >https://1drv.ms/f/s!Ars591e1yxqWopFYAG2lTo7YLMQg_A.

Comment: Okay, I forgot to add `iferror`. I edited the answer.